# login username or email field required without validation

Tags: html, forms, authentication, validation

I have a simple login form with username/email and password fields, and two buttons, one for a normal login and one for LDAP login.
The normal login requires email/pwd, while the LDAP login requires username/pwd

I already have it working with a input-text field but I've discovered that input-email helps mobile user to have a specialized keyboard with @ and . as shortcuts.

What's the easiest way to achieve that mobile friendly keyboard? My idea was to somehow use input-email and disable validation, but I'd still like to maintain the automatic "required" validation

```html
<div class="form-floating">
    <input required autofocus type="text" class="form-control" 
    id="username" name="username" placeholder="username or email">
    <label for="username">username or email</label>
</div>
```

Ignore bootstrap for the purpose of the final result :)

Comment: I don't see a good solution to this, with the current form layout. You only know whether the user needs the special keyboard for emails when they actually press one of the submit buttons. The obvious solution would be to let them make this choice earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the initial type to email (have the benefit of user friendly keyboard) and alter the type on button click to text/email accordingly to remove the restriction on submit if needed:

```html
<form>
<div class="form-floating">
    <input required autofocus type="email" class="form-control" 
    id="username" name="username" placeholder="username or email">
    <label for="username">username or email</label>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="normal" onclick="document.getElementById('username').setAttribute('type','email')">
<input type="submit" value="LDAP" onclick="document.getElementById('username').setAttribute('type','text')">
</form>
```

Comment: This means that people who want to enter an user name have to use the keyboard for email addresses. Is that acceptable?

Comment: This is perfect for my use case, usernames have all characters any email will have, so it's fine.
I've just added the fact that after a failed validation on the LDAP button it will switch back to the type=email.

Comment: it will display invalid message

Answer (score 0):

The solution by Ali Sheikhpour will display the invalid message when you press Enter in the empty field and then continue typing:

[image]

So the direction could be to imitate the email input in a shadow DOM. Works in the mobile Chrome. Should be tweaked for Firefox/Safari.

[image]

```js
const shadow = $email.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
const email = document.createElement('input');
email.type = 'email';
email.required = true;

const style = getComputedStyle($username);
const keys = Object.keys(style).filter(key => key.match(/\D/));

Object.assign(email.style, {
  ...Object.fromEntries(keys.map(key => [key, style[key]])),
  position: 'absolute',
  backgroundColor:'transparent'
});

email.addEventListener('input', e => $username.value = email.value);

setTimeout(() => email.focus());

$username.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1');

Object.assign($username.style, {
  pointerEvents: 'none',
});

shadow.appendChild(email);

$form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = new FormData($form);
  
  console.log(...data);
});
```

```css
.form-control{
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<form id="$form">
<div id="$input" class="form-floating">
    <span id="$email"></span>
    <input id="$username" required autofocus type="text" class="form-control" 
    placeholder="username or email" name="username">
    <label for="$username">username or email</label>
    <div>
    <input id="password" required type="password" class="form-control" 
    placeholder="password" name="password">
    <label for="password">username or email</label>
    </div>
</div>
<button>Login</button>
</form>
```